# Wikipedia API get random article

Tags: java, android, layout, mediawiki

Hi i need to display text(using json format) from random wiki page whenever user opens their app and that text must comprise of minimum 10 sentences.
I have read other SO questions and Wikipedia API docs and the best i could find is this url:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&grnlimit=1

But problem with this url many times it displays content that has less than 10 sentences and there is no parameter to set minimum characters or sentences or words in this query.

There is one more thing which is "extracts" that extracts random artcles based on conditions such as number of sentences, characters etc so i used this one:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&generator=random&exsentences=10

But this url also does not result in what i am looking for.

Please help.

Comment: This is a good question. I tried a ton of different ways with the API and I haven't been successful... if nobody finds a way to do it through the API, you could always cache a few articles and pick the first one that meets your requirements.

Comment: thanks but that would not be feasible lets suppose i cache 10 articles and if none of them satisfies my condition i will have to again run my query which will lag my UI

Comment: Is there some way where i can find number of words in a page using wiki api?